# primefaces remoteCommand optional ids inside of update attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am porting my application from Richfaces to Primefaces and faced a problem

If inside of atribute in `<pe:remoteCommand>` is id, which is not present in the view, page rendering will fail.
Is there a way to make these IDs optional?
Here is my stacktrace

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with expression
>   "menu" referenced from "j_idt1251:j_idt1254".
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
>     org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
>     org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:149)
>     org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>     org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
>     com.mediamid.war.shared.filter.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:214)
>     com.mediamid.war.shared.filter.WindowsSSOControlFilter.doFilter(WindowsSSOControlFilter.java:40)

it was working perfectly fine with Richfaces

Any ideas?

Comment: Simply remove the ID from `update`?!

Comment: I've got many views which use the save remoteCommand, therefore I do not want to recreate this function on every single page just because one id is missing

Comment: So you have a parent view with a remote command which requires every including view to contain the required ID? Not very good style, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came up with the following solution. Maybe it could be useful for somebody

PrimeFaces provide neat feature - referencing of component using JQuery selector. 
Selector should be provided inside of update="@(selector)" 
If element was not found, page will be able to render, which is exactly the required behavior.

```
<pe:remoteCommand name="JSFdeleteCartItem"
                  update="@(#cartMenu,#cartMenu1,#cart,#messages)"
                  actionListener="#{cart.removeItem()}"
                  status="ajaxLoading"
                  limitToList="true">
                <pe:assignableParam name="param1" assignTo="#{cart.indexDeleteCartItem}"/>
            </pe:remoteCommand>
```